# Swift: Using UIButtons as UIImages

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

I'm working on a dice game with Swift. I want give players the choice to hold a 'dice' for a turn when they tap on it. Because of this I want to use UIButtons as the dices. I got the dices working as UIImages and now I want to transfer the UIImages over to UIButtons. But while doing this I got an error:

> Argument labels '(named:)' do not match any available overloads.

I'm kinda clueless and don't really know how to fix this.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var dice1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var dice2: UIButton!

let stenenArray = ["Steen1, Steen2, Steen3, Steen4, Steen5, Steen6"]

var randomDiceIndex1 : Int = 0
var randomDiceIndex2 : Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    updateDiceImages()
}


func updateDiceImages(){
    dice1 = UIButton(named: stenenArray[randomDiceIndex1])
    dice2 = UIButton?(named: stenenArray[randomDiceIndex2])

    randomDiceIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
    randomDiceIndex2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `dice1` and `dice2` are *IBOutlets*, I would consider that there is no need to re-initialize them.

*Even though, `UIButton(named: ...)` seems to be weird!*

So what you should do instead of -the weird initialization- for the buttons:

```
dice1 = UIButton(named: stenenArray[randomDiceIndex1])
dice2 = UIButton?(named: stenenArray[randomDiceIndex2])
```

is to simply set an image for each one, by using [`setImage(_:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623997-setimage) method:

```
dice1.setImage(UIImage(named: stenenArray[randomDiceIndex1]), for: .normal)
dice2.setImage(UIImage(named: stenenArray[randomDiceIndex2]), for: .normal)
```

**Update:**

It seems that you would need to implement `updateDiceImages()` as:

```
func updateDiceImages() {
    randomDiceIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
    randomDiceIndex2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))

    dice1 = UIButton(named: stenenArray[randomDiceIndex1])
    dice2 = UIButton?(named: stenenArray[randomDiceIndex2])
}
```

which means that you should generate the random values for both `randomDiceIndex` variables *before* setting the UIButtons images, otherwise the first roll would be always zeros.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it got rid of the error. The buttons now are images, but it doesn't get the randomDiceIndex to work. The function I made seems to do nothing now.

Comment: @G.Venem it seems that you should generate the random values for `randomDiceIndex` variables before setting the UIButtons images...

Answer (score 5):

There is no initializer for `UIButton` using an argument `named:`. Guessing from your `dice1` and `dice2` variables being declared as `@IBOutlet`, you probably already have the buttons and now only want to assign the images instead of creating new buttons:

```
dice1.setImage(UIImage(named: stenenArray[randomDiceIndex1]), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
dice1 = UIButton(named: stenenArray[randomDiceIndex1])
dice2 = UIButton?(named: stenenArray[randomDiceIndex2])
```

with

```
dice1.setImage(UIImage(named: stenenArray[randomDiceIndex1]), for: .normal)
dice2.setImage(UIImage(named: stenenArray[randomDiceIndex2]), for: .normal)
```

Comment: Cool, it got rid of the error. But now if I run it on the simulator the images of the dices on the buttons won't show. It just shows the words 'buttons' on the simulator.

Comment: @G.Venem Remove "Button" label from your UIButton in the XIB/StoryBoard